# PHP foreach loop returning the matching item

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to return the matching item's value in foreach loop. I have tried with the blow code but it is not returning correctly. If the matches with the last item, it won't returns the correct value.

```
//$bonuses = count => amount
Array
(
    [15] => 25
    [30] => 50
    [46] => 100
)

// getting keys to compare the count
$counts = array_keys($bonuses);

foreach ($bonuses as $count => $bonus) {
    if ($total_number_of_products <= next($counts)) {
    $tti = 'Items: '. $total_number_of_products. ' Bonus: '. $bonus. '<BR/>';
    }
}
```

The loop should returns the item if less than or equal. If the count is `46` or higher (in this case) the output should `100`. Now it is returning `50`.

Comment: So the bonus for 10 products is 0? and 40 would be 50?

Comment: That's correct. It's a flat bonus. User will get only when the count reaches to the number. No in-betweens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you need to output the prior bonus value only until you reach the next key. This is one way to do that:

```php
function get_bonus($total_number_of_products) {
    $bonuses = array(15 => 25, 30 => 50, 46 => 100);
    $bonus = 0;
    foreach ($bonuses as $num_products => $next_bonus) {
        if ($total_number_of_products < $num_products) break;
        $bonus = $next_bonus;
    }
    return $bonus;
}
```

Sample usage:

```php
foreach ([10, 20, 30, 45, 46, 50] as $products) {
    echo 'Items: '. $products. ' Bonus: '. get_bonus($products). '<BR/>' . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Items: 10 Bonus: 0<BR/>
Items: 20 Bonus: 25<BR/>
Items: 30 Bonus: 50<BR/>
Items: 45 Bonus: 50<BR/>
Items: 46 Bonus: 100<BR/>
Items: 50 Bonus: 100<BR/>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/lNjn7)

Note you can make a minor simplification by adding a `0 => 0` entry to `$bonuses`, then you can remove the `$bonus = 0` line i.e.

```php
function get_bonus($total_number_of_products) {
    $bonuses = array(0 => 0, 15 => 25, 30 => 50, 46 => 100);
    foreach ($bonuses as $num_products => $next_bonus) {
        if ($total_number_of_products < $num_products) break;
        $bonus = $next_bonus;
    }
    return $bonus;
}
```